# C# DocumentFormat OpenXML Word 2013 Repeating Content Control

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have created a Word 2013 document with a series of content controls. I have a bunch of text controls in the header and then a table that has a repeating content control with more text controls

What I am trying to achieve is via my C# program build some XML that I can use to map to my content controls.

My XML looks like this

```
<Job>
     <JobNo>123</JobNo>
     <Staff>Chris Smith</Staff>
     <Client>Client 2</Client>
     <DateReceived>2015-05-08</DateReceived>
     <SampleNo>3</SampleNo>
     <Department>Product</Department>
     <Status>Open</Status>
     <JobSamples>
       <Sample>
          <SampleNo>1</SampleNo>
          <SampleIdentification>Identifier</SampleIdentification>
          <AnalyticalTest>AnalyticalTest</AnalyticalTest>
          <SampleMatrix>SampleMatrix</SampleMatrix>
          <TypeOfTest>TypeOfTest</TypeOfTest>
          <SampleStaff>SampleStaff</SampleStaff>
          <SampleDueDate>SampleDueDate</SampleDueDate>
      </Sample>
      <Sample>
          <SampleNo>2</SampleNo>
          <SampleIdentification>Identifier</SampleIdentification>
          <AnalyticalTest>AnalyticalTest</AnalyticalTest>
          <SampleMatrix>SampleMatrix</SampleMatrix>
          <TypeOfTest>TypeOfTest</TypeOfTest>
          <SampleStaff>SampleStaff</SampleStaff>
          <SampleDueDate>SampleDueDate</SampleDueDate>
      </Sample>
  </JobSamples>
</Job>
```

I have created a word template that has a Custom XML part and have mapped the fields appropriately.  My RepeatingContentControl has been mapped to the  node and correctly displays two rows of Samples data

However at run time my XML may contain 1....N Samples and so I want the Repeating Content Control to correctly refresh

When I run my code all the other control outside of the repeating content control get refreshed, but the repeating control doesn't.

Do I need to get a handle on the repeating content control in code and add or remove rows accordingly?

If so, how can I do that?

If not, how can I get my repeating control to refresh?

Here is my code:-

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Job Sheet.docx");
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true))
{
    // Creates and saves JobXML file
    CreateCustomXML(job);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "JobXML.xml"));

    MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    //delete old xml part
    mainPart.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(mainPart.CustomXmlParts);

    //add new xml part
    CustomXmlPart customXml = mainPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
    using (StreamWriter ts = new StreamWriter(customXml.GetStream()))
    {
        ts.Write(doc.OuterXml);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for mapping? I mean xmlmapping the content control with the xpath